# When uploading images in Amazon S3 it tells me that the file is damaged

Tags: php, laravel, file, amazon-s3

Currently I want to upload the images that the client chooses to the Amazon S3 service and in fact it seems that it already does so because it uploads a file and tells me that it weighs 92kb the same as the file I am choosing but when I want to open it with the path that is It gives me the following error:

> The image `<image path>` cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Code Laravel

```
public function SaveImage($request){
    if ($request->hasFile('inputFile')) {
        $image = $request->file('inputFile');
       $fecha= date("m-d-y");
        $name = $fecha."_".$request->txtNombre.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $destinationPath = public_path('UploadProfile');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $filePath=$destinationPath."\\".$name;
        $initPath="Perfil\\".$name;
      Storage::disk('s3')->put($initPath, $filePath);
    return $urlImage= Storage::cloud()->url($initPath);
    }
}
```

the strangest thing is that it does not mark me errors, everything runs correctly but if it shows me that the files were uploaded in the panels of the buckets, besides if I upload directly through the buckets and open the path if it opens right way.

The image path would be as follows:

```
https://katanasystem.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Profile/01-05-20_david.jpg
```

Comment: Access denied. check your bucket policy if you want to make this image publicly accessible.

Comment: Seems you are not uploading a file. You are uploading a the location on the server only. Try this `Storage::disk('s3')->put($initPath, $image->__toString);` or `Storage::disk('s3')->put($initPath, $image);`